# In Moon (2009 film), who are in the hallucinations?

Tags: moon-movie

In the beginning of *[Moon (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1182345/)*, Sam had a hallucination of a teenage girl in a yellow dress.  He later sees a figure standing on the moon surface, but this one is barely discernible.

> Is the first hallucination is daughter? If so, how could he have an hallucination of her if he never saw her as a teenage and still think she was 3 years old?

And who is the second hallucination? Was it really an hallucination?

Comment: Maybe it's foreshadowing of the fact said character isn't 3 anymore? :) I'll have to rewatch the movie.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer in this [Duncan Jones interview](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/15096/duncan-jones-interview-the-man-who-made-moon). (Spoilers)

According to this, these visions are caused by [twin telepathy](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwinTelepathy) (or clone telepathy in this case) and all hallucinations are his daughter, because he is talking about "these visions" (plurals).  Anyway the second hallucination is hardly anything else than an hallucination because he is alone on the moon and all the others clones are either dead or frozen.

> **In the film itself, why did Sam hallucinate seeing his teenage daughter near the start of the film? Was this ever intended to be picked up on more explicitly?**
>
> Okay, I've answered this a couple of times before. This is my story and I'm sticking with it! Basically, Moon is intended to be a hard science fiction film, which means we try to build and extrapolate on present day science. Occasionally, and that is one of the moments, we start to touch into soft science fiction, which is more fantastical. But, I still argue that there is a roughly scientific idea behind it.
>
> You hear stories of identical twins when they're separated, sensing or having a feeling or awareness of anything major or traumatic that happens to their identical twin, even if they're not in contact. So, the idea is that Sam on the base is able to sense and feel that there exists a daughter, a girl, which is the daughter of the original Sam back on Earth. That's how they're all connected and that's why Sam's having these visions. Because, basically, this girl means so much to the original Sam.

Comment: I would have thought that maybe a previous clone had found out about the daughter and a part of that memory had been transfered, possibly hinting that the company had killed off clones who knew too much before.