# Changing gravity in Moon (2009 film) - simply a mistake or was there an explanation?

Tags: hard-sci-fi, gravity, moon-movie, artificial-gravity

Last night I watched [Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_(film)) and it struck me that the gravity seemed to change depending on Sam's location:

- On the Moon's surface, gravity seemed to be as expected, as evidenced by Sam's slow movement.
- Inside the base, the gravity was just like on Earth. Was there some kind of "gravity generation device" like most "soft" sci-fi, eg [Star Trek](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity)?
- Most surprising, to me, was that the gravity even seemed Earth-like *inside the lunar rovers!* Was that just a production error?

I ask because [I've read that Moon was intended to be hard sci-fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21023/143) but this was (to me) an obvious failing.

Was this a production error or was there an in-universe explanation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that the film's Director was well aware of the issue but apparently decided to ignore it for the sake of story-telling (and presumably also for budgetary reasons).

In an interview for [EMPIRE](http://www.empireonline.com/interviews/interview.asp?IID=982), he unequivocally shows that this was a consideration;

> **Interviewer:** *And is it true that you had a screening for Buzz Aldrin?*
>
> **Duncan Jones:** *Well, I gave him a copy of the film. In fact, there's been three astronauts who've seen it, one of whom – Buzz –
>   who’s been on the Moon, and it's been wonderful to hear that they
>   appreciate the film. **Obviously, they’re very much aware that elements
>   in it aren’t scientifically correct - the base is not one sixth of the
>   Earth’s gravity, for instance** - but they're very forgiving.*

Answer (score 6):

Because low-G scenes set indoors are difficult to film and look stupid, Hollywood has evolved the convention that a breathable atmosphere provides Earth-normal gravity as a side effect, and you only experience low-G when you're out in the vacuum. It's obviously scientifically wrong, but you'll find very few films that don't use it, even such bastions of hard SF as *2001: A Space Odyssey* (although Kubrick did have the excuse that no one actually knew how people move in lunar gravity at the time he was filming).

Comment: actually, the station in space odyssey rotates, and When I watched it I assumed the gravity was caused by that force. idk if the rotation is fast enough though.

Comment: @samboosalis The space station scenes in _2001_ are fine; it's the indoor scenes on the Moon that are wrong.

Comment: Filmmakers could easily solve this problem without having to simulate low gravity in indoor scenes, just by having moonbases shown to be ring-shaped in exterior shots--then viewers who care about such things would be free to imagine the rooms inside the base are mounted on a monorail or something so they can travel in circles. The centrifugal force can provide artificial gravity just as easily on the surface of the moon (or any other low-gravity body) as in a space station, you just have to have the floors at an angle so the sum of real + artificial gravity is a vector orthogonal to the floor.

Comment: A spinning moon base would have 1g pulling you "down" but 1/6 g constantly pulling you 90 degrees sideways. You've two different vectors acting on you. You could _possibly_ compensate by angling the floor to be perpendicular to the sum of the forces, but I'm not sure how this would _feel_